# git push cloned repo to own repo

Tags: git, push, bitbucket

I'm completely new to git.
I try to push a cloned Bitbucket directory (from my local computer) to my own Bitbucket. but, It only copied the files of the original repo (the one that is online, that I cloned)?

And when i do git push, I get the answer:
The current branch master has no upstream branch.
So when I do that, i get Everything up-to-date, but my files I created locally aren't in my branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newly created files make no part of version control until you add them:

```
$ git add file_foo
$ git add file_moo
```

and than you should `commit` them before you make the push:

```
$ git commit -a
```

Comment: So it has nothing todo with cloning the repo of somebody else (which I don't want to write to), I would like to write to my own repo?

And do I have to add every file manually? That seems a bit odd?

Comment: Yep, you should just add them to git and commit them and they will be part of the source control

Comment: Hmmn, this worked for 1 file.
If I would like the complete directory to push, is that possible? Or not? Maybe by creating a new repo? Or ...? Thank you for getting me this far!

Comment: @user3634184 yes, you could do this with directories but be sure that the directory has only what you want to add inside.